# How to include an archive file in your c code

Tags: c

I'm making an archive file, which I am then trying to include in my code, but when I try to `#include 'libutils.h'`, I get an error:

```
 src/indexer.h:8:10: fatal error: 'libutils.h' file not found
 #include "libutils.h"
```

my make command is:

```
gcc -g -std=c11 -Wall -pedantic -o indexer src/indexer.c  -L. -lutils.a
```

my file structure is:

```
Indexer/

 libsutil.a  obj/ src/ makefile 

obj/

 web.o list.o hashtable.o            //These are the files in the archive file

src/

 web.c web.h list.c list.h hashtable.c hashtable.h indexer.c indexer.h
```

Comment: where is the `libutils.h` file?

Comment: There isn't one, that's the .a file. Do I need to make a .h file? Am I misunderstanding what an archive file is?

Comment: What's the point of the archive file then?

Comment: It contains compiled code in object file format, it's like an object file but commpressed and may contain several object files, you only need it for linking.

Comment: right, so do I only include the files that make up the archive file?

Comment: Why do you want to include it anyway?

Comment: It's for a homework, and we're required to. I'm not sure I understand what the point of it is, or how to implement it, which is making it very hard to include.

Comment: There could be some functions implemented that were compiled as an archive so if you use those functions then you can link to the file to generate the actual executable, do you have the source code from where the archive file was generated?

Comment: Yeah, I made the archive file myself. I have all of the source code for it.

Comment: I have a makefile already made.

Comment: Do I leave the #include 'web.h' and such in it even though those are in the archive file?

Comment: `#include` is for header files, where the function declarations are, the compiler needs the function declarations to know what the return and how to call them, and then after compilation is done, the last stage is linking all the object files togather there you include the archive files via `-larchifile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to `include` anything, remove the

```
#include "libutils.h"
```

from the `.c` file, and your compilation command will be

```
gcc -g -std=c11 -Wall -pedantic -o indexer src/indexer.c  -L. -lutils
```

Comment: That's still not working for me. It's still complaining that it can't find the file.

Comment: The `-l` flag is for shared linking. Simply add `libutils.a` to your linking line.

Comment: Then I guess it's because OP's lib file is actually called `libsutil` instead of `libutils` :)